# Making a dot in the center of a bitmap C#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I have tried looking for this but I can't seem to find any code to work with a bitmap or a png. I am doing some calculations to find the center of a cluster of black points from a binarized image. I want to know if the center is correct by drawing a red dot at the center points. All the graphics methods I used draw the red dot on the form not on the saved image itself. How can I draw a red dot on the binarized image? (Binarized basically means applying a threshold to an image to get where the light is). I will attach my code below. Basically I press a button and then some grayscale algorithm happens then I apply Bernsen threshold, and save that image as "result". Then I go over the image result and do my calculations. I want to draw a red dot with the XCenter and YCenter on result.

```
    //Function for going through the image in windows of 2 pixels
    private ArrayList getNeighbours(int xPos, int yPos, Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ArrayList neighboursList = new ArrayList();

        int xStart, yStart, xFinish, yFinish;

        int pixel;

        xStart = xPos - 2;
        yStart = yPos - 2;

        xFinish = xPos + 2;
        yFinish = yPos + 2;


        for (int y = yStart; y <= yFinish; y++)
        {
            for (int x = xStart; x <= xFinish; x++)
            {

                if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > (bitmap.Width - 1) || y > (bitmap.Height - 1))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    pixel = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y).R;

                    neighboursList.Add(pixel);
                }
            }
        }

        return neighboursList;
    }


 private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 48; i < 49; i++)
        {
            BlackPoints = 0;
            SumX = 0;
            SumY = 0;
            Xcenter = 0;
            Ycenter = 0;

            pictureBox2.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Salma\Desktop\Images\" + i + ".png");
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image);


            /////////////Gray Scale First////////////////////
            byte red, green, blue, grayscale;

            for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
                {
                    red = image.GetPixel(x, y).R;
                    green = image.GetPixel(x, y).G;
                    blue = image.GetPixel(x, y).B;

                    grayscale = Convert.ToByte((red + green + blue) / 3);
                    image.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(grayscale, grayscale, grayscale));
                }

            }
            //////////////////////////////////////////////
            //////////////Bernsen Threshold///////////////
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image);

            int iMin, iMax, t, c, contrastThreshold, pixel;

            contrastThreshold = 110;

            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

            for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
                {
                    list.Clear();

                    pixel = image.GetPixel(x, y).R;
                    list = getNeighbours(x, y, image);
                    list.Sort();

                    iMin = Convert.ToByte(list[0]);
                    iMax = Convert.ToByte(list[list.Count - 1]);

                    t = ((iMax + iMin) / 2);

                    c = (iMax - iMin);

                    if (c < contrastThreshold)
                    {
                        pixel = ((t >= 160) ? 0 : 255);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pixel = ((pixel >= t) ? 0 : 255);
                    }
                    result.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(pixel, pixel, pixel));

                }

            }

            pictureBox3.Image = result;
            result.Save("C:\\Users\\Salma\\Desktop\\Threshold\\" + i + ".png");

            for (int h = 0; h < result.Height; h++)
            {
                for (int w = 0; w < result.Width; w++)
                {
                    //Get the color at each pixel
                    Color now_color = result.GetPixel(w, h);

                    //Compare Pixel's Color ARGB property with the picked color's ARGB Property 
                    if (now_color.ToArgb() == Color.Black.ToArgb())
                    {

                        SumX += w;
                        SumY += h;

                        BlackPoints++;


                        Xcenter = SumX / BlackPoints;
                        Ycenter = SumY / BlackPoints;



                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: make that Xcenter - 5/2 etc in the coordinates

Comment: What do you mean? What would that do to the coordinates?

Comment: The usual method to alter the final file (instead of just the representation on the form) is to save the image, from the one you create in memory to the file, replacing the original. Working directly with the file is harder, and would not be done with the graphic libraries (you would have to study the file format and use the file IO functions to do it, or look of a third party library). Instead, I suggest to just use [Image.Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.save(v=vs.110).aspx). Is that not what you are asking? Make it clearer.

Comment: It would help if you cleaned up the code a bit. Remove references to `progressBar1` (not relevant to the post) and move code blocks into methods where we can follow the logic. Having all the code under a `button_Click()` method makes it hard to decipher the intent.

Comment: It would move the oval to the actual center, if that was what you want. The question is unclear and the code seems confusingly irrelevant.

Comment: can you also show the declaration of `getNeighbours()`?

Comment: So **where in your code do you try to draw the dot**?

Comment: If you have code to draw it right on the form, just do the same but with a graphics object taken _from the image_ instead of from the form.

Comment: @ja72 I have edited the code above to include the declaration of the function

Comment: I used this to draw a red dot on the image but it drew on the form itself                            `void DrawDBuff(Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics g2 = Graphics.FromImage(B);
            DrawScene(g2);
            g.DrawImage(B, 0, 0);
        }

        void DrawScene(Graphics g)
        {
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            g.DrawEllipse(Pen.Red, Xcenter, Ycenter, 5, 5);`

Comment: @SalmaKassem Please, if you have additional code relevant to the question, _edit the question and put it in there._

Comment: @SalmaKassem You should use a picture box control for displaying an image, instead of painting the image on the form... but besides that, you never clean up the `Graphics` object you make, meaning the changes are probably never confirmed. Call it as `using(Graphics g2 = Graphics.FromImage(B)) { DrawScene(g2); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All the graphics methods I used draw the red dot on the form not on the saved image itself.**

**How can I draw a red dot on the binarized image?**

This is an implementation, Of how you can draw a circle on the image.

It's poor but it works.

```
public void DrawCircl(Point index, Bitmap img,int Radius) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
    {
        double x = index.X - Radius * Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI / 360 * i);
        double y = index.Y - Radius * Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI / 360 * i);
        img.SetPixel((int)x, (int)y, Color.Red);
    }
}



//This is your image from the pictureBox1
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

// I am targeting the middle of the image, Your case would be the binarized image
Point index = new Point(img.Size.Width / 2, img.Size.Height / 2);

// Calling Draw Cirle Method, the last parameter is the radius.
DrawCircl(index,img,40);

// After the circle been drawn you save the image where you want
img.Save(@"[Path to Save IMG]");
```

Comment: This works exactly like how I want it! But it is super slow T.T

Comment: What's slow ? Can you be a bit more specific ? I mean everything in there is customizable.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa The `SetPixel` function is known to be notoriously slow, especially when used in a loop like that, because it locks and unlocks the underlying image memory on every call.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa When drawing the circle around the center points, the image keeps flickering,like around 5-8 times before the circles is drawn completely and so on. So it takes around 2 mins roughly for each image for the circle to be drawn. Otherwise it works exactly like how I wanted it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in the calculation of the center. For one you are doing `Xcenter = SumX / BlackPoints;` and `Ycenter = SumY / BlackPoints;` within the loop. There are also, many other issues, like:

**Consequitive Assignments**

```
bool flag = false;
flag = true;
```

or

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    // inside the loop
    list = getNeighbours(x, y, image);
```

and **Unnecessary multiple calls to slow functions**

```
red = image.GetPixel(x, y).R;
green = image.GetPixel(x, y).G;
blue = image.GetPixel(x, y).B;
```

Also **Use of ArrayList** instead of the recommended `List<byte>` or whatever type is returned by `getNeighbours()`.

---

I took the liberty to try to cleanup the code somewhat:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GrayScaleFirst();
    BernsenThreshold();
    if(GetBlackPixelCenter(out int xc, out int yc))
    {
         // use xc, yc
    }
}

void GrayScaleFirst()
{
    /////////////Gray Scale First////////////////////
    byte grayscale;
    Bitmap image=new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);            
    if(image==null)
    {
        return;
    }
    for(int y=0; y<image.Height; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x<image.Width; x++)
        {
            Color color=image.GetPixel(x, y);
            grayscale=Convert.ToByte((color.R+color.G+color.B)/3);
            image.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(grayscale, grayscale, grayscale));
        }
    }
    pictureBox1.Image=image;

}

void BernsenThreshold()
{
    Bitmap gray=pictureBox1.Image as Bitmap;
    Bitmap image=new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

    int iMin, iMax, t, c, contrastThreshold, pixel;

    contrastThreshold=110;

    for(int y=0; y<image.Height; y++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x<image.Width; x++)
        {

            Color color=gray.GetPixel(x, y);
            pixel=color.R;
            var list=GetNeighboursSorted(x, y, image);

            iMin=list[0];
            iMax=list[list.Count-1];

            t=((iMax+iMin)/2);

            c=(iMax-iMin);

            if(c<contrastThreshold)
            {
                pixel=((t>=160)?0:255);
            }
            else
            {
                pixel=((pixel>=t)?0:255);
            }
            image.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(pixel, pixel, pixel));

        }
    }
    pictureBox1.Image=image;

}

bool GetBlackPixelCenter(out int x_center, out int y_center)
{
    Bitmap image=pictureBox1.Image as Bitmap;

    int black=Color.Black.ToArgb();

    x_center=0; y_center=0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int h=0; h<image.Height; h++)
    {
        for(int w=0; w<image.Width; w++)
        {
            //Get the color at each pixel
            Color now_color=image.GetPixel(w, h);

            //Compare Pixel's Color ARGB property with the picked color's ARGB Property 
            if(now_color.ToArgb()==black)
            {
                x_center+=w;
                y_center+=h;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    x_center=count>0?x_center/count:0;
    y_center=count>0?y_center/count:0;

    return count>0;
}

static List<byte> GetNeighboursSorted(int x, int y, Bitmap image)
{
    var list=new List<byte>();

    int i1=Math.Max(0, y-1), i2=Math.Min(y+1, image.Height-1);
    int j1=Math.Max(0, x-1), j2=Math.Min(x+1, image.Width-1);

    for(int i=i1; i<=i2; i++)
    {
        for(int j=j1; j<=j2; j++)
        {
            if(i!=y && j!=x) 
            {
                list.Add( Convert.ToByte(image.GetPixel(j, i).GetBrightness()*255));
            }
        }
    }

    list.Sort();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: @ja72 Thank you for this edit! I actually did have a lot of performance issues. But I do not get the problem with my calculation. I am doing `Xcenter= SumX/BlackPoints;` within the loop because the loop goes over the images in the file. And I need to do this calculation for every image **i**.